# How to use the selenium.PhantomJS() on webpage already downloaded by scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, phantomjs

```
def parseList(self, response):
    dr=webdriver.PhantomJS()   
    dr.get(response.url)
    pageSource = dr.page_source
    print dr.page_source
```

The webpage is already download by scrapy (Included in the `response.body`), and `dr.get(response.url)`  will download again.

Is there any way to let selenium directly use `response.body`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about saving the HTML file with content from the `response.body` and than do something like

```
url = "file:///your/path/to/downloaded/file.html"
dr.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Scrapy doc](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html):

> Regardless of the type of this argument, the final value stored will
>   be a str (never unicode or None).

I'm assuming you're using Selenium in Python if you're using Scrapy. You can parse that `response.body` string with [lxml](http://lxml.de/parsing.html) or another library. What exactly do you mean by "let selenium use `response.body`"?